# How to change font style in Linux terminal?

Tags: font

I know this question has been asked many times, but what I've noticed is that the majority of them seem to be for gVim or Vim for Windows rather than Linux command line Vim.

I'm just wondering how I'd be able to change the font style for my terminal Vim. Doing

```
set guifont=Consolas
```

doesn't do anything, probably because I'm not using a GUI. Doing

```
set font=Consolas
```

gives an error because it's an unrecognized line of code.

Answer (score 4):

To change the font used by terminal Vim or Neovim, you need to change the font the your terminal emulator uses. The exact settings vary between different terminal emulators.

For example, if you are connecting to your Linux server on Windows via [mintty terminal](https://mintty.github.io/), you can go to `Options --> Text` to change the font.

For other terminal emulators, you can consult their official documentation.